# gremlin outputs different from as seen on the internet, I think in bytes

Tags: groovy, titan, gremlin

How to get gremlin output normal indices along with v

Currently it outputs something like this

```
gremlin> g.V
WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [()]. For better performance, use indexes
gremlin> juno = g.addVertex(null);
==>v[128824]
gremlin> june = g.addVertex(null);
==>v[128828]
gremlin> jape = g.addVertex(null);
==>v[128832]
```

But as I saw on the internet it should be output something like this when a vertex is added in the graph

```
gremlin> g.V
WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [()]. For better performance, use indexes
gremlin> juno = g.addVertex(null);
==>v[1]
gremlin> june = g.addVertex(null);
==>v[2]
gremlin> jape = g.addVertex(null);
==>v[3]
```

The same problem occurs when I try to load about 10000 vertices. All these vertices have _id field in it but after loading this field is gone. It also not that the vertices have been loaded with this id....same is the case with _type field its also not present after loading.

I need these id and type because they map to something in other table too.

Here is a look at my rexter doghouse about the 3 loaded vertices

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrheG.png

So bit confused about all this stuff.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When vertices are added to Titan an `Element` identifier is assigned.  That value is up to Titan and you should not expect it to start at "1" or any other specific number when you do.  If you need there to be some kind of number like that you should add it yourself.

With respect to the `_id` and `_type` fields, I'm assuming that you are referring to fields found in JSON output from Rexster.  Note that those are Rexster fields that are appended to the output.  `_id` is always there and should map directly to `Vertex.id()` or `Edge.id()` depending on the data you are returning.  `_type` just refers to the whether the JSON returned is representative of a "vertex" or an "edge".  That data is not stored in Titan itself.

Comment: Does that mean that whatever value we give to id in json file, titan will not use it and these ids (and also types ) are just limited to json reader

Comment: Almost all Blueprints implementations ignore the ID that is submitted to them - so Titan is not so different in that respect.  Create your own ID property key and index on that if you need such a thing.  You don't need to ever send the `_type` because you are either doing a POST (if using REST) to the `/graph/vertices` or `/graph/edges` resource in which case the "type" is known or you are calling the `addEdge` method in Gremlin to create the edge explicitly.

Comment: The only reason `_type` is present in results is to be helpful when you return a mixed results of vertices and edges and need to distinguish between the two.